# The "Order" button in onepage checkout doesn't work

Tags: onepage-checkout, magento-1.8

I'm trying to setup a web store using Magento 1.8. Onepage chekout got stuck in the payment methods. Following the workflow outlined here http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards I fixed that issue, however now when I arrive at the "order review" step the "Order" button doesn't work. There are no errors in the JS console.

Can someone help?

Comment: look here
http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/610464/

Comment: I assume you have some custom code but sadly the link you posted appears to not be correct. Could you please post your code in your question.